# Paperclip error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am getting the following error when uploading an image on the admin panel of spree (RoR e-commerce platform):

Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError in Admin/imagesController#create

/tmp/stream.4724.0 is not recognized by the 'identify' command.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: identify is a command in ImageMagick that detects the file format of an image. Does the same thing happen when you try with a different image?

Comment: Same issue. It works locally fine, but on production on my ubuntu slice it breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the wrong `identify` command (which is part of ImageMagick) is being called (or, perhaps, it isn't installed at all).  Can you confirm the path to this command on your server using:

```
which identify
```

Once you've determined where this command is installed (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`) then you can tell Paperclip about it by adding the following to your environment.rb (or production.rb etc) file:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '/usr/local/bin/'
```

(this is for Paperclip 2.2 and above.  If you're using an earlier version you should use `:image_magick_path` not `:command_path`)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by
*$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying this is the solution but it wouldn't hurt to check your file permissions.  Can the user running imagemagick access files in /tmp/ ?